# Equidistantly spaced divs with percentages for responsive design

Tags: html-lists, responsive-design, percentage, spacing, text-justify

[Working example](http://www.haselden.co.uk/media-query.html) and [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YT3KZ/3/)

Trying to come up with a solution for this that creates a `ul li` list that displays items spaced apart equidistantly, but using percentages.

The solution needs to be able to work responsively, that is the blocks (images with text overlayed) would reduce in both size, and the space between them down to an iPad size. At typical mobile phone resolution, they would stack.

There are three elements, but the advantage of using percentages would be that an extra one could be added without having to redo much of the CSS. Hopefully the blocks (in this case `li` items) would just adjust their sizes and spaces accordingly.

I tried having a play with some equidistant CSS tricks over [here](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) but they aren't really suitable for responsive.

I plan to use `max-width:100%` to make the images resize to the max width of the current `li` so that larger images can be used without the need for resizing (saves time when swapping images around and means that the same image can be used elsewhere on the site)

`li` list doesn't need to be used, would be open to using a simple `div` or `span` structure.

Any ideas?

**First issue:** In my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YT3KZ/3/) example you can see that the images align and resize based on the window size. However the farthest right element isn't flush with the right edge (they're all typically left aligned). Though I have added `text-align:justify` it doesn't seem to be having the affect desired

**Second issue:** Three being non divideable evenly is a problem. 30% isn't a true third, and 33% seems to push it out.

**Third issue:** Whitespace. Is there a way to stop the evil whitespace between `li`'s that are placed on different lines? Must I sacrifice readable HTML to get rid of the whitespace?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bottomWide">
    <ul>
    <li><img src="#" alt="text"></li>
    <li><img src="#" alt="text"></li>
    <li><img src="#" alt="text"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

## bottomWide{

```
width:85%;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid red;}
```

## bottomWide ul{

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

}

## bottomWide li{

```
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
width:30%;
text-align:justify;
```

}

## bottomWide img{

```
max-width:100%;
```

}

**Media Query for stacking (works well)**

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
    #bottomWide li{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

http://jsfiddle.net/YT3KZ/3/

I changed the li to `float:left;` rather than `display:inline-block;` and added a `margin-left: 1%;` and made the width 32.333% to compensate for the 1% margin and spread it across the div.

This will position li's with a 1% margin on the left and cut off 1% on the right so you need to counter that with a negative margin on the ul or you could add a positional class to do this.

```
margin-left:-1%;
```

Another way to do it is to make the container wider than your page width so they position properly and use a negative margin/padding to compensate the part which would be cut off.

PS. just noticed you didn't want a gap.. remove the `1% margin` and change it the `li` to `33.333%`

http://jsfiddle.net/YT3KZ/7/

Note: I haven't removed the css that is not required. E.g. `text-align:justify;` so you can clean it up.

Comment: Brill! Yeah I threw justify in there just to see, didn't expect it to work!